# How can I acess a map value inside an object with struts2?

Tags: java, json, struts2

I have this map inside a class named Code:

```
class Code{
    Map<Field, FieldValue> properties = new HashMap<Field, FieldValue>()
}
```

And I have a list of codes, but I want to access the map properties values in the browser trough JSON and using Struts2, so I'm trying something like this:

```xml
<action name="CodeJSON" method="list" class="codeAction">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="includeProperties">
                ^codes\[\d+\]\.properties
            </param>
        </result>
</action>
```

I also tried this:

```xml
^codes\[\d+\]\.properties\[\d+\]\.key
```

And other similar things. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the map properties values?

Comment: Have you tried w/o `includeProperties`?